How to multiply all elements of a first array by elements another one?
Suppose we have two arrays of different lengths:
let array1 = [22, 42, 28, 100, 28, 48, 38, 48, 26, 32, 58, 36, 28, 42, 42, 38, 28, 28, 38, 24, 32, 38, 38, 28, 46, 38, 42, 46, 32, 46, 38, 48, 9, 6, 5, 8, 5, 56, 24, 32, 5, 46];

let array2 = [25, 50, 75, 100, 150, 250];

It's necessary multiplication be performed in this way:
22x25, 22x50, 22x75 ... 42x25, 42x50 ...
How to do this correctly?

Use the nested for-loop

What have you tried ? Do you want to store or to print the results ?

What is holding you back to perform these multiplications? Did you get incorrect results?

I'll add the received values via textContent to the few div's

Get ready to dive into the exciting world of JavaScript! We're going to multiply each element of one array by each element of another, using nested loops. Here's a handy code snippet to get you started:

javascript

let array1 = [22, 42, 28, 100...];

let array2 = [25, 50, 75, 100...];

let resultArray = [];

for (let i = 0; i< array1.length; i++) {

for (let j = 0; j< array2.length; j++) {

resultArray.push(array1[i] * array2[j]);

}

}

console.log(resultArray);

In this thrilling piece of code:

We've got our arrays array1 and array2 all set up.

We create a shiny new empty resultArray where we'll store our multiplication results.

Our nested loops are at work here: the outer loop takes a tour through array1, while the inner loop explores array2.

Inside these loops is where the magic happens: we multiply elements from both arrays and push the results into our resultArray.

And voila! We log resultArray to reveal all those multiplied values.


-NAMASTE(0_0)

Really magic :)

You could map the products.


const
    array1 = [22, 42, 28, 100, 28, 48, 38, 48, 26, 32, 58, 36, 28, 42, 42, 38, 28, 28, 38, 24, 32, 38, 38, 28, 46, 38, 42, 46, 32, 46, 38, 48, 9, 6, 5, 8, 5, 56, 24, 32, 5, 46],
    array2 = [25, 50, 75, 100, 150, 250],
    result = array1.map(v => array2.map(w => v * w));

result.forEach(a => console.log(...a));
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }




You can use Array::reduce() and Array::map() to collect the values:


let array1 = [22, 42, 28, 100, 28, 48, 38, 48, 26, 32, 58, 36, 28, 42, 42, 38, 28, 28, 38, 24, 32, 38, 38, 28, 46, 38, 42, 46, 32, 46, 38, 48, 9, 6, 5, 8, 5, 56, 24, 32, 5, 46];

let array2 = [25, 50, 75, 100, 150, 250];


const result = array1.reduce((r, n) => (r.push(...array2.map(n2 => n * n2)), r), []);

console.log(result);




Here you can do one thing...
let array1 = [22, 42, 28, 100, 28, 48, 38, 48, 26, 32, 58, 36, 28, 42, 42, 38, 28, 28, 38, 24, 32, 38, 38, 28, 46, 38, 42, 46, 32, 46, 38, 48, 9, 6, 5, 8, 5, 56, 24, 32, 5, 46];

let array2 = [25, 50, 75, 100, 150, 250];

const res = array1.map(a => array2.map(b => a*b))

